# How to use a string as an already exist list function in python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I want to use a string as an already exists list function.
For example i got from a user as input: 'append'

How can i use this string as a function directly?

For example:

```
function_name = str(input(n)) # let say it is append
arr = []

arr.function_name(9)  #Of course it is not working because it is string. Not a function.
```

Comment: This is the kind of practice that cause HUGE security issue!

Comment: Yes i agree @VincentBénet But i need to use it for a while.. Because i am sure that upcoming inputs will be a certain function name in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
>>> a = []
>>> getattr(a, 'append')(1)
>>> a
[1]
```

That being said, it's not the best idea to execute arbitrary code based on user input. You should check the input against a collection of allowed methods first.

Answer (score 2):

All functions are attributes of the respective object. You can use the `getattr` function to get the function callable and then call it.

For Eg. ,

```
function_name = str(input("")) # let say it is append
arr = []

#Get the attribute and call it
# You can check if callable(function_to_call) to make sure its a function as well.
function_to_call = getattr(arr, function_name)
function_to_call(10)

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using is not possible.

But you can use this method instead...

```
function_name = str(input(n))
arr = []

if function_name == "append":
    arr.append(9)
```

or you can use `getattr`:

```
function_name = str(input(n))
arr = []

getattr(arr, fucntion_name)(9)
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add that. It was a rarely used item.